# React.js. How to show only first object of fetched API?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show only first object of API, which I succeed in console, but when I put it in useState, it gives me an error 
`Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`
here is my code, I guess I have a typo, but can't find

````
import Meme from "./Meme";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const fetchData  = () => {
  fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
  .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then(result =>{ setData(result.data.memes) /*.then(result =>{ setData(result.data.memes[0]<<-- this will give an error*/
  console.log(result.data.memes[0])
  }
  )
  .catch(err => console.log("error"))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])



  return (
    <div className="App">
   {data.map((element, index) => (
          <Meme
            key={index}
            title = {element.name} 
            image = {element.url}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

```
````

Comment: Your setData is an array, not an object. If you are going to show first object only. make your state receive object, then `setData([result.data.memes[0]])` but remember your render, should change also

Comment: Is your response from the API an array or an object? Also, if you change `data` to be just one result, as opposed to a collection of results, then you'll have to change what you're rendering, since it won't be `data.map(...)` any more for a single result

Comment: In my case API is an array of objects. I made it work, but  what is interesting, that I didn't change useState to object, I left it the same ```  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```,  I changed only what you said ```setData([result.data.memes[0]])```, and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this :

```
setData(result.data.memes)
```

To :

```
setData([result.data.memes[0]])
```

---

**OR**

> if you need only first element all the time, you should do it like
>   this

Change :

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

setData(result.data.memes)
```

To :

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

setData(result.data.memes[0])
```

---

**OR**

You can just use the first element in your render.

Comment: I made it work, but what is interesting, that I didn't change useState to object, I left it the same ``` const [data, setData] = useState([])```;, I changed only what you said ```setData([result.data.memes[0]])```, and it worked.

Comment: I made it work, but what is interesting, that I didn't change useState to object, I left it the same  ```const [data, setData] = useState([])``` .  I changed only what you said ```setData([result.data.memes[0]])```, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
    setData(result.data.memes[0]);
```

OR

```
{data.slice(0, 1).map((obj) => (...))}
```